# jQuery converted codes wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there I am trying to convert JavaScripts code to jQUery for better performance.

Here's my JS codes:

```
(function() {

    var body_container = document.body,
        content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
        open_menu = document.getElementById( 'open-button' ),
        close_menu = document.getElementById( 'close-button' ),
        checkifOpen = false;

    function init() {
        initialize_process();
    }

    function initialize_process() {
        open_menu.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        if( close_menu ) {
            close_menu.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        }

        // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
        content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if( checkifOpen && target !== open_menu ) {
                toggleMenu();
            }
        } );
    }
```

Now here's my converted jQuery version of this javascript:

```
(function() {

    var body_container = $('body'),
        content = $( '.content-wrap' ),
        open_menu = $( '.open-button' ),
        close_menu = $( '.close-button' ),
        checkifOpen = false;

    function init() {
        initialize_process();
    }


    function initialize_process() {
        open_menu.bind( 'click', toggleMenu );
        if( close_menu ) {
            close_menu.bind( 'click', toggleMenu );
        }

        // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
        content.bind( 'click', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if( checkifOpen && target !== open_menu ) {
                toggleMenu();
            }
        } );
    }
```

For some reason this codes won't work. Just wondering where did I went wrong. Especially the part where I bind elements in replace with addEventListener function of JavaScript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For better performance? jQuery almost never offers better performance than Vanilla JS.

Comment: `if( close_menu )` { is always going to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the correct selectors.  The original code has this:

```
document.getElementById( 'open-button' )
```

Which identifies an element with the `id` "open-button".  The new code has this:

```
open_menu = $( '.open-button' )
```

Which identifies an element (or set of elements) with the `class` "open-button".  To use an `id` you need to use a `#`:

```
open_menu = $( '#open-button' )
```

There are likely to be further problems, but starting from this problem nothing else will work as expected...

Comment: thanks how about this line of code here:  open_menu.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu ); should I use bind?

Comment: @RizabelIdoz: If you're going to use jQuery, then I guess it makes sense to use jQuery's functions.  `.click()`, `.on()`, etc.  Note that, as mentioned in a comment, the use of jQuery is *not* to address performance.  It's to provide a simple, fluent API over common tasks.  The goal is to have clearer code, *not* more performant code.